# How to make a if statement over after a certain thing has been hidden for a certain time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a game and I need to know if you can make a `if` statement that makes it like this:

```
if object.hidden = YES for 5 seconds{ 
    do these things
}
```

Could someone please tell me if this is possible, and if so how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

Put a timestamp on your object at the time it was hidden.  Then convert your test into a "how long has this object been hidden".  Pseudocode (since I don't actually have experience with objective C):

```
if hidden and elapsed time since hidden > 5 seconds:
    do stuff
```

Comment: im not exactly sure how to put a timestamp on my object

Comment: If it's an object, presumably you add another field to it, and make it some kind of time-related value.  In a pinch, it could be `time_t` or `clock_t`, but neither of those are great choices for games.  Usually with games, you have a mechanism to retrieve the game time, using the clock type of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [CACurrentMediaTime()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CACurrentMediaTime), for an accurate time interval.

*sample:*

```
CFTimeInterval start = CACurrentMediaTime(); 

for(int i=0; i<=10000; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%i", i);
} 

CFTimeInterval elapsed = CACurrentMediaTime() - start;

NSLog(@"elapsedTime : %f", elapsed);
```

Make sure you've added QuartzCore framework in your traget's settings

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `Object` and build that functionality in. Something like:

```
@interface ObjectSubclass : Object

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

@end

@implementation ObjectSubclass

-(void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden{

    [super setHidden:hidden];

    if (hidden){

        if (self.timer) {
            [self.timer invalidate];
        }

        self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(doStuff:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer
                                     forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    } else {

        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```